# Show that $\lim a_n =0$ if $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|<1, \forall n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that if $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|<1, \forall n \geq 1$, then

$$\lim a_n =0 $$

I only could conclude that the sequence is decreasing and the modulus sequence is decreasing and bounded. But it didnt help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't true. Perhaps you meant $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_{n+1}/a_n|<1$?

Comment: Let be $a_n = 0.4 + \frac{1}{n}$. Then $$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<1\text{,}$$
but $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0.4$.

Comment: @DavidMitra : $\:$ ... or that with limsup instead of lim. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Indeed, guys. Maybe the exercise meant something different.

Answer (score 0):

Set $\rho:=\lim_{n\to\infty }\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$. If $\rho<1$ then $$0<\frac{\rho+1}{2}<1$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\left(\frac{1+\rho}{2}\right)^n=0.$$

Since $$\rho=\lim_{n\to\infty }\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|,$$
there exists an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that 
$$n\geq N\implies \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\leq \frac{\rho+1}{2},$$
and so $$|a_{n+1}|\leq\frac{\rho+1}{2}|a_n|$$
if $n\geq N$. Recursively, we obtain
$$|a_n|\leq \left(\frac{1+\rho}{2}\right)|a_{n-1}|\leq   \left(\frac{1+\rho}{2}\right)^2|a_{n-2}|\leq\cdots\leq  \left(\frac{1+\rho}{2}\right)^{n-N}|a_{N}|$$
and so $$\lim_{n\to\infty }|a_n|=0.$$ Moreover,
$$-|a_n|\leq a_n\leq |a_n|.$$
Therefore, by the [squeeze theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), we obtain that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }a_n=0.$$

Comment: You can replace the initial lim with limsup. $\;$